# Getting entries of child grids of currently expanded row in `igHierarchicalGrid`

Tags: ignite-ui, iggrid, rowexpansion

I am trying to achieve a functionality in which what i want is to get the data of children of the row, that is currently being expanded. I came through the Example on [Ignite UI Help Forum](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/94943/469278.aspx), but it does not help me with the issue. The Example is demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmup8gbd/). The

```
ui.owner.allChildren().data().igGrid.dataSource.data()
```

is giving me data of all expanded rows children. I want this functionality to achieve at every level i.e. Suppose a row at level 2 is expanded, then, I want to be able to get the data of child grid associated with that row.

In the example above mentioned fiddle, I want to be able to get the data of `Food` row children, when food is expanded, and of `Beverages` row children, when this is expanded.

I am not able to figure out, how can i filter out those entries, which do not belong to a particular row.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a way for you how to extract the specific child grid data:

```
$(ui.parentrow.context).find("table[data-childgrid=true]")
                       .data()
                       .igGrid
                       .dataSource
                       .data();
```

This should still be made easier to be accessed using the event arguments more directly!